# Regex - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing

Tags: regex, vb.net, search

I'm creating a basic text editor and I'm using regex to achieve a find and replace function. To do this I've gotten this code:

```
Private Function GetRegExpression() As Regex
    Dim result As Regex
    Dim regExString As [String]
    ' Get what the user entered
    If TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        regExString = txtbx_Find2.Text
    ElseIf TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        regExString = txtbx_Find.Text
    End If

    If chkMatchCase.Checked Then
        result = New Regex(regExString)
    Else
        result = New Regex(regExString, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    End If

    Return result
End Function
```

And this is the **Find** method

```
 Private Sub FindText()
    ''
    Dim WpfTest1 As New Spellpad.Tb
    Dim ElementHost1 As System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost = frm_Menu.Controls("ElementHost1")
    Dim TheTextBox As System.Windows.Controls.TextBox = CType(ElementHost1.Child, Tb).ctrl_TextBox
    ''
    ' Is this the first time find is called?
    ' Then make instances of RegEx and Match
    If isFirstFind Then
        regex = GetRegExpression()
        match = regex.Match(TheTextBox.Text)
        isFirstFind = False
    Else
        ' match.NextMatch() is also ok, except in Replace
        ' In replace as text is changing, it is necessary to
        ' find again
        'match = match.NextMatch();
        match = regex.Match(TheTextBox.Text, match.Index + 1)

    End If

    ' found a match?
    If match.Success Then
        ' then select it
        Dim row As Integer = TheTextBox.GetLineIndexFromCharacterIndex(TheTextBox.CaretIndex)
        MoveCaretToLine(TheTextBox, row + 1)
        TheTextBox.SelectionStart = match.Index
        TheTextBox.SelectionLength = match.Length

    Else
        If TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show([String].Format("Cannot find ""{0}""   ", txtbx_Find2.Text), Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        ElseIf TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show([String].Format("Cannot find ""{0}""   ", txtbx_Find.Text), Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        End If
        isFirstFind = True
    End If
End Sub
```

When I run the program I get errors:

- For `?`, `parsing "?" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing.`; and
- For `*`, `parsing "*" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing.`

It's as if I can't use these but I really need to. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is the test input? You seem to provide that through the user interface, but we don't know what you enter in that user interface...

Comment: what do you mean by the test input? if it helps, the user enters text in a textbox and then when the user clicks find, it uses the text in the textbox to search and select that particular text.

Comment: What do you enter to get these errors? See answer below, `?` and `*` have a special meaning...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?` and `*` are *quantifiers* in *regular expressions*:

- `?` is used to specify that something is optional, for instance `b?au` can match both `bau` and `au`.
- `*` means the group with which it binds can be repeated zero, one or multiple times: for instance `ba*u` can bath `bu`, `bau`, `baau`, `baaaaaaaau`,...

Now most *regular expressions* use `{l,u}` as a third pattern with `l` the lower bound on the number of times something is repeated, and `u` the upper bound on the number of occurences. So `?` is replaced by `{0,1}` and `*` by `{0,}`.

Now if you provide them **without any** character before them, evidently, the regex parser doesn't know what you mean. In other words if you do (used `csharp`, but the ideas are generally applicable):

```
$ csharp
Mono C# Shell, type "help;" for help

Enter statements below.
csharp> Regex r = new Regex("fo*bar");
csharp> r.Replace("Fooobar fooobar fbar fobar","<MATCH>");    
"Fooobar <MATCH> <MATCH> <MATCH>"
csharp> r.Replace("fooobar far qux fooobar quux fbar echo fobar","<MATCH>");
"<MATCH> far qux <MATCH> quux <MATCH> echo <MATCH>"
```

If you wish to do a "*raw text find and replace*", you should use [`string.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

**EDIT**:

Another way to process them is by escaping special regex characters. Ironically enough, you can do this by replacing them by a regex ;).

```
Private Function GetRegExpression() As Regex
    Dim result As Regex
    Dim regExString As [String]
    ' Get what the user entered
    If TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        regExString = txtbx_Find2.Text
    ElseIf TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        regExString = txtbx_Find.Text
    End If

    'Added code
    Dim baseRegex As Regex = new Regex("[\\.$^{\[(|)*+?]")
    regExString = baseRegex.Replace(regExString,"\$0")
    'End added code

    If chkMatchCase.Checked Then
        result = New Regex(regExString)
    Else
        result = New Regex(regExString, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    End If

    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: So ? and * are special characters for Regex to do certain operations however, Is there a way to skip it and just pass it as a regular string so that when the user searches for symbols it will just select it and highlight it if it's found?

Comment: @F4z: modified, you can do it by inserting two lines in the function. Since I'm however a C# programmer, there might be some syntax errors, in that case, please comment.

Comment: Code works fine when searching for text (plain text without symbols) however when I search for symbols like *?^$() it doesn't seem to be working. For ? and * it doesnt select the text just moves the carret to the next character and other symbols like ^$ regex related it just doesn't find them

Comment: Nevermind, looks like i had an extra '/' in '//$0'. Thank you! Hep was greatly appreciated.