# C# Regex error Quantifier {x,y} following nothing

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net, code-conversion

I wrote a small program that converts English text into a Pig Latin in Visual Basic. I am currently converting it into C# language. And during the conversion process, I am stumbling upon a regex-related error.

The rules I am working with are:

- String starts with a, e, i, o, or u
- String contains a, e, i, o, u, or y

In VB, I wrote those rules as following (both variables are bool):

```
isVowel = words(counter) Like "[aeiou]*"
isInside = words(counter) Like "*[aeiouy]*"
```

Where `Private index As Integer = -1
       Private words(index) As String`.

And the For loop

```
For counter As Integer = 0 To words.Length - 1
    isVowel = words(counter) Like "[aeiou]*"
    isInside = words(counter) Like "*[aeiouy]*"

    //proceed with conversion logic
Next counter
```

Upon research, I used the following [article](https://www.dotnetperls.com/regex) as a reference to help with conversion. I ended up converting those lines as following:

```
isVowel = Regex.IsMatch(words[counter], "[aeiou]*");
isInside = Regex.IsMatch(words[counter], "*[aeiouy]*");
```

Now I am testing both of these rules on my first string in the text, which is **adam**. In VB, for the first letter `a` both isVowel and isInside return true. For C#, isVowel returns true, but isInside returns the following error instead of true as I hoped for:

```
Quantifier {x,y} following nothing
```

I searched threads here in SO (those were case specific, but I tried using its answers as possible pointers) along with SO wiki it suggested. I tried updating the rule based on what I learned from wiki and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798285/parsing-quantifier-x-y-following-nothing) (and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810949/regex-quantifier-x-y-following-nothing), I'll use just a couple to link out of 10+ threads that I found) about *, +, and ?. I tried using both + and ? on preceding character pattern. But it returns the same error.

**Can you please point me in the right direction of why this rule returns the error? Am I missing something regex C#-specific?**

Comment: I suppose you need to replace `*` *wildcard* pattern with `.*` in the *regex* pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Like this `.*[aeiouy].*`?

Comment: `Like` requires a full string match, thus, you need `*` in the wildcard pattern. `Regex.IsMatch` finds *partial* matches, so, you do not even need those `.*`. Just use `isInside = Regex.IsMatch(words[counter], "[aeiouy]");`